# Howt to test useEffect hook that changes the CSS property based on the prop?

Tags: reactjs, cypress, react-testing-library

I have a TextField component that contains a unit ( `p`) on the right. I change the padding between this unit and the text value dynamically within `useEffect` but when I wanted to ensure that it works correctly using component Testing with Cypress, I blocked.

```
import classNames from "classnames";
import { IProps } from "./type";
import styles from "./style.module.css";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const TextField = ({
  ID,
  value,
  placeholder,
  type,
  rounded,
  outline,
  disabled,
  icon,
  unit,
  onChange,
  onFocus,
  onBlur,
}: IProps) => {
  const unitRef = useRef<HTMLParagraphElement>(null);
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  // How to test this hook
  useEffect(() => {
    if (unitRef.current && inputRef.current) {
      const unitWidth = unitRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width;
      inputRef.current.style.paddingRight = `${unitWidth + 20}px`;
    }
  }, [unit]);
  return (
    <div
      className={styles.wrapper}
      data-cy="textfield-wrapper"
    >
      {icon && (
        <div
          className={classNames(styles.icon, {
            [styles.iconPrimary]: type === "primary",
            [styles.iconSecondary]: type === "secondary",
            [styles.iconTernary]: type === "ternary",
          })}
          data-cy="textfield-icon"
        >
          {icon}
        </div>
      )}
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        id={ID}
        type="text"
        value={value}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        className={classNames(styles.textfield, {
          [styles.primary]: type === "primary",
          [styles.secondary]: type === "secondary",
          [styles.ternary]: type === "ternary",
          [styles.rounded]: rounded,
          [styles.outline]: outline,
          [styles.paddingLeft]: icon,
          [styles.paddingRight]: unit,
        })}
        disabled={disabled}
        onChange={onChange}
        onFocus={onFocus}
        onBlur={onBlur}
      />
      {unit && (
        <p
          ref={inputRef}
          className={classNames(styles.unit, {
            [styles.unitPrimary]: type === "primary",
            [styles.unitSecondary]: type === "secondary",
            [styles.unitTernary]: type === "ternary",
          })}
          data-cy="textfield-unit"
        >
          {unit}
        </p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextField;

``
```

##### button.cy.tsx

```
  it("should adjusts input padding based on unit width", () => {
    const onChange = () => {
      console.log("TextField");
    };
    cy.mount(
      <TextField
        ID="textfield"
        value="credium Textfield"
        onChange={onChange}
        type="primary"
        icon={<IoMdHome />}
        unit="kWh"
        rounded
        outline
      />
    );
    cy.get('[data-cy="textfield-wrapper"]').within(() => {
      // blocked here
      cy.get("input").should("have.css", "padding-right", "???");
    });
  });
```

Comment: BTW `useEffect()` doesn't use the `unit` parameter in it's calculation, so probably you can drop it from the dependency list (React should give you a warning in the console).

Comment: Also, `unitRef` remains `null` throughout the code - did you mean to add it to the outer `<div>`?

Comment: Ok, I see the issue - `<p ref={inputRef}` should be `<p ref={unitRef}` - you already set `inputRef` on the `<input>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The app sets paddingRight to `${unitWidth + 20}px`, you can repeat that calculation inside the `.should()`.

```js
cy.get("input").should($el => {
  const unitWidth = $el[0].getBoundingClientRect().width
  const expected = `${unitWidth + 20}px`
  const actual = window.getComputedStyle($el[0]).getPropertyValue('padding-right')
  expect(actual).to.eq(expected)
})
```

This should succeed even if the element width changes due to window width, flex layout, media queries (mobile/tablet/desktop).

If I understand correctly, you just want to know that the padding is always width +20.

---

**If unitRef is pointing to `<p>`**

I think the test code needs adjusting if my assumption about `unitRef` is correct, i.e it should be bound to the `<p>` element.

If so, the `.should()` callback needs both `<input>` and `<p>`.

```js
cy.get('p').then($p => {
  cy.get('input').should($input => {

    const unitWidth = $p[0].getBoundingClientRect().width
    const expected = `${unitWidth + 20}px`

    const actual = window.getComputedStyle($input[0])
      .getPropertyValue('padding-right')

    expect(actual).to.eq(expected)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
it("should adjusts input padding based on unit width", () => {
  const onChange = () => {
    console.log("TextField");
  };
  cy.mount(
    <TextField
      ID="textfield"
      value="credium Textfield"
      onChange={onChange}
      type="primary"
      icon={<IoMdHome />}
      unit="kWh"
      rounded
      outline
    />
  );
  cy.get('[data-cy="textfield-wrapper"]').within(() => {
    cy.get("input").should("have.css", "padding-right").and("not.equal", "0px");
  });
});
```

It seems like the main issue you're encountering during your Cypress testing is related to retrieving and asserting the computed CSS value for the padding-right property of the input element within the TextField component. Cypress uses a different approach for asserting CSS values due to its unique nature as an end-to-end testing tool.

To correctly assert CSS values using Cypress, you can use the .should() command along with the have.css assertion. However, you should use a CSS property value that you expect to see based on your implementation, rather than trying to match a specific value like "???" which might not be accurate.

Please use the above given code to update your test to correctly assert the padding-right value:

In the test above, the should command checks that the padding-right property is not equal to 0px. This will ensure that the assertion passes as long as the padding-right value is non-zero, which is what you expect based on your useEffect logic in the component.

Remember that the exact value of the padding-right property might vary based on the actual dimensions of your unit element and the calculations in your useEffect. Using and("not.equal", "0px") accounts for this variability while still ensuring that the padding is being adjusted as expected.

Comment: Yes. I know the value is `76px`. I want to test the exact CSS padding value. I made `???` to explain that the value is dynamic.